# How to make a namespace within a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I would like to utilize my own custom namespaces in a PowerShell .ps1 script or a .psm1 module.  Is this possible?  If so, what is the syntax to do this?

I found a related link here:
[Breaking the Powershell namespace limit of global,script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675638/breaking-the-powershell-namespace-limit-of-global-script)

It seems like I will need to make my own custom object, or possibly use a custom associative array for this?

I would like to be able to call my function like this:

```
[MyCoolNamespace]::Get-CrazyYall
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A module name is similar to a namespace.  For example:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Command
```

is the same as

```
Get-Command
```

Normally you don't use module qualified names when invoking commands (cmdlets, functions, or aliases), but it comes in handy if you do have a conflict or want to be 100% certain you are invoking the function you meant to.

Comment: thanks!  I think this is actually more along the line of what I want to do.  Basically I wanted a namespace so I didn't have to write out long function names (i.e. pseudo namespace).

Comment: I accepted this because it was "pure" PowerShell and provides what I wanted, albeit with a different name...

Comment: This is far from complete: for example I cannot reach variables exported from the module. Functions and aliases  are visible indeed

Answer (score 10):

Create a custom type with a static method:

```
PS C:\> Add-Type @'
>> using System;
>> public class MyCoolNamespace {
>>   public static string Foo() {
>>     return "Foo";
>>   }
>> }
>> '@
>>
PS C:\> [MyCoolNamespace]::Foo()
Foo
```

Comment: thanks!  I guess it's only possible by reverting back to C# syntax?  I was hoping to write my functions in PowerShell, but put them in a namespace.  Is this possible?  Is it easy?  For instance, what if I already have the function Get-Foo written in PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this in plain PowerShell.

Comment: To me this doesn't answer the question because it's just leveraging C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using PSTypeNames.

```
$Var = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = [string]::Empty
    bar = $false
}

$Var.PSTypeNames.Insert(0, 'My.Namespace')
```

$var | get-member

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good practice.